# Use results from one sql query in another where statement (subquery?)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I see many similar questions but they're either so complex I can't understand them, or they don't seem to be asking the same thing.

It's simple: I have two columns: users (dmid) and downloads (dfid).

1. Select all users who downloaded a specific file:

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT dmid FROM downloads_downloads where dfid = "7024"
   ```
2. Using the users above, find all the files they all downloaded:

   ```
   SELECT dfid from downloads_downloads WHERE dmid = {user ids from #1 above}
   ```
3. Count and order the dfid results , so we can see how many downloads each file received:

   ```
   dfid    dl_count_field
   ----    --------------
   18       103
   3        77
   903      66
   ```

**My attempt at answering.**

This seems close, but MySql bogs down and doesn't respond even after 30 seconds--I restart Apache eventually. And I do not now how to structure the count and order by without getting syntax errors because of the complex statement--and it may not even be the right statement.

```
SELECT dfid from downloads_downloads WHERE dmid IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT dmid FROM `downloads_downloads` where dfid = "7024")
```

Comment: You shouldn't use double quotes (`"`) for character literals, use single quotes instead. The double quotes are a MySQL thing and won't work with other DBMS (because in standard SQL double quotes are used for identifiers, not for literals). And if that dfid is a numeric value, you shouldn't be using any quotes all. Numbers don't need quotes.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

```
SELECT dfid,count(*) 
from downloads_downloads 
WHERE dmid IN (
    SELECT dmid 
    FROM downloads_downloads 
    where dfid = "7024"
)
group by dfid
```

or using a self join

```
select t1.dfid,count(*)
from downloads_downloads t1
inner join downloads_downloads t2
on t1.dmid = t2.dmid
where t2.dfid = "7024"
```

if this takes too long then you will probably need to post an explain plan (google it!)

Comment: for me solution #1 works, and its quite easily understandable , but can you please explain, me solution #2 i can under stand self join

Comment: @paul-creasey I know this is old, but can you explain the second code?

Comment: Heads up: if your ultimate goal is to perform an `update`, the first approach will result in an error, which this other answer helped me resolve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Comment: I used both of these for my use case, dumped the first solution into the second solution's where statement.