# MySQL use query in another query

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I am new to MySQL. My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779338/use-results-from-one-sql-query-in-another-where-statement-subquery) one, but the answer given over there is based on a subquery. As a Microsoft Access user I'd like to know if you can have query definitions in your database that you can use in the joins of an sql statement, just the way you are using tables. My provider mentioned stored procedures, but after some quick research I wonder if this is the same thing. Isn't a stored procedure more like a user defined function that you can use in your sql statement?

Comment: What you're looking for is views. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html

Comment: That is probably just what I was looking for!

Comment: It is. It's just different terminology but the same concept

Comment: If Barmar's comment had been given as an answer, I could mark it as answer and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

[Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58701721/mysql-use-query-in-another-query/58717212#comment103699444_58701721) was just what I needed:

> What you're looking for is views. [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html)