# MySQL: Taking mulitple IDs returned from one query and passing the value in the "IN" of another query

Tags: mysql, join

So let's say that I have a query:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tablename`
```

This will returns some IDs in rows. Now I want to use these IDs to get data from another table with the 'IN' function.

```
SELECT `somecol` FROM `anothertable` WHERE `parent` IN ( {IDs here} )
```

I could do this with PHP using 2 different queries. But I wanted to know how or can it be done with MySQL alone, using only one query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use results from one sql query in another where statement (subquery?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779338/use-results-from-one-sql-query-in-another-where-statement-subquery)

Answer (score 0):

Use *exists*:

```
SELECT somecol
FROM anothertable a
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM tablename t WHERE t.ID = a.parent
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in your first query inside you second query:

```
SELECT 
`somecol` 
FROM 
`anothertable` 
WHERE 
`parent` 
IN (SELECT `id` FROM `tablename`)
```